# The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java

I am getting this error "The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

```
public class employee {
    public static void main (String args[ ]){
          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           int sum = 10; // getting error over here
    }
}
```

But if I change the code as shown below, the error disappears

```
public class employee {
    public static void main (String args[ ]){
          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //add braces over here
                 int sum = 10; 
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, a declaration statement isn't valid as the body of loop - because it would be pointless. Admittedly that's an odd error message to get, but you know how to avoid it. I would recommend *always* using braces for loops etc.

Comment: Unrelated but your class name should start with a capital letter.

Comment: The specific reason why the first is illegal is ["Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).

Comment: @harold i agree it, you can mark qn as duplicate.

Comment: @patrick that was a typo